# php if condition not working in laravel controller

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel-5

Help post php if condition not working in laravel controller

```
<div class="price-box float-left">
                                <?php if('.$home_base_price.' != '.$home_discounted_base_price.'): ?>
                                        <del class="old-product-price strong-400">
                                                '.$home_base_price.'
                                        </del>
                                <?php endif ?>
                                        <span class="product-price strong-600"> 
                                         '.$home_discounted_base_price.'
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you aware you are comparing literal strings instead of values?

Comment: _"condition not working in laravel controller"_ Surely doesn't look like one